# Coordinate system choice in mapproxy demo

Tags: mapproxy, configuration

I have a question about the mapproxy demo page.

I added wmts and wms to the services config, so the demo page lists the configured layers in the WMS and the WMTS part.

```
services:
  #sets up how to make the source data available
  demo:
  wmts:
  wms:
    #srs sets the coordinate reference systems as which you want to make your data available. MapProxy reprojects the source data very well to these projections.
    srs: ['EPSG:3857','EPSG:900913']    
    image_formats: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

But the problem here I have is that only the EPSG:900913 SRS is shown in the WMTS part. The WMS part shows a drop-down menu with the configured SRS. How can I achieve that under WMTS I can choose between all SRS as in WMS?
The same with the image formats. The WMTS part shows only png.

I use mapproxy 1.7.1.

**UPDATE**:
Meanwhile I have figured out that only the SRS and image format which are used in the cache are shown. If I change the SRS used for caching to another one, the SRS on the web site changes as well.

[image: No SRS choice for WMTS layers.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the MapProxy mailing list I now know that there is no other option to provide multiple SRS and image formats than creating multiple caches.

MapProxy needs a cache per SRS and image format for WMTS. If more flexibility is needed, WMS needs to be used.